# Skullcandy 50/50 - Weird Noises Even When Audio Is Off

Tags: laptop, audio, music, mute, earbuds

Bought Skullcandy 50/50, connected to my laptop and noticed "laser" like or circular saw cutting like sounds that can be hardly heard. **I muted everything** and still hear them. This happens only with Skullcandy 50/50 but not on iLuv or ZAGG smartbudds.

What causes these sounds?

Comment: And do you hear those on any other device? Like, take an MP3 player, another computer, a TV, anything.

Comment: It does not happen with smartphone and MP3 player. It happens with laptop and LCD TV.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a MacBook Pro, this site may help you: [Background hiss and noise when using earbuds on MacBook Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/49030/background-hiss-and-noise-when-using-earbuds-on-macbook-pro)

I have the same problem with ALL of my skullcandy headphones (I've tried a few) but none of the headphones from Sony have this problem. The solution mentioned on the linked site didn't work for me but maybe it'll work for you.